# Visual Studio Expand/Collapse keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio, if I have a code file open, I can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to collapse all code blocks, regions, namespaces, etc.

How to I do the opposite and expand everything?

I have Googled this, but cannot seem to find a shortcut that works!

Answer (score 380, accepted):

**Collapse to definitions**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>

**Expand all outlining**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>

**Expand or collapse everything**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>

*This also works with other languages like TypeScript and JavaScript*

Comment: And I googled it and got your answer;)

Comment: Dont' press all three buttons at once! Hold CTRL and then press M followed by either O or X. ;-)

Comment: Note that the CTRL + M + L keyboard sequence is the equivalent of doing Edit > Outlining > Toggle All Outlining.

Comment: @jrh expand/collapse, toggle...same same.

Comment: @series0ne Sure, I mostly put that there because I was looking for it under the View menu, not the Edit > Outlining menu.

Comment: @jrh aye it was well placed. Feel free to update the answer

Comment: When I do this in vs2017, I got "The Key Combination (Ctrl + M, O) is not a command." It's actually (Ctrl + M, Ctrl + O), found out by going into environment settings. I'm not sure if things changed in vs2017.

Comment: @DanChase do you have any plugins installed that might have overridden the key mapping? Something like Resharper for example? (not suggesting Resharper DOES do this, but it wouldn't surprise me...)

Comment: @DanChase P.S. I have VS2017 Enterprise installed and it works here.

Comment: Actually, there is also CTRL + M + A, which collapses all, although I don't really see why it's useful.

Answer (score 141):

As you can see, there are several ways to achieve this.

I personally use:

Expand all: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Collapse all: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

Bonus:

Expand/Collapse on cursor location: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

Comment: Without wanting to repeat the other comments there, but Ctrl M M is awesome and going to save me so much time!

Comment: V useful bonus about expand collapse on location

Comment: CMM +1 internet cookie for you. Not what I was looking for... BETTER! than what I was looking for.

Comment: Ctrl M M  doesn't work in last VS

Comment: Can confirm Ctrl+M+M works in Visual Studio 2019

Comment: "True collapse all" is Ctrl + M + A. Ctrl + M + O collapses to definitions – this is what I use all the time, as it produces a kind of a "table of contents" of a class.

Comment: Is there an inverse version of CTR+M+M ?

Comment: @Allstar Simply press CTRL+M+M again :-)

Answer (score 33):

Visual Studio 2015:

```
Tools > Options > Settings > Environment > Keyboard
```

**Defaults:**

Edit.CollapsetoDefinitions: <kbd>CTRL + M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

Edit.CollapseCurrentRegion: <kbd>CTRL + M</kbd> +<kbd>CTRL + S</kbd>

Edit.ExpandAllOutlining: <kbd>CTRL + M</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL + X</kbd>

Edit.ExpandCurrentRegion: <kbd>CTRL + M</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL + E</kbd>

**I like to set and use IntelliJ's shortcuts:**

Edit.CollapsetoDefinitions: <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + NUM-</kbd>

Edit.CollapseCurrentRegion: <kbd>CTRL + NUM-</kbd>

Edit.ExpandAllOutlining: <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + NUM+</kbd>

Edit.ExpandCurrentRegion: <kbd>CTRL + NUM+</kbd>

Comment: CME is what I was looking for. One internet cookie for you.

Answer (score 22):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

It's called Edit.StopOutlining

Comment: Thanks for this!...Would be interested to know how you formatted your shortcuts here to look like keys from a keyboard!

Comment: @series0ne Wrapped them with kbd tags :)

Comment: @congusbongus It doesn't print if you press Ctrl + M first.

Answer (score 13):

For collapse, you can try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and expand using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. This works in VS2008.

Comment: It's `CTRL + M + O` - letter O, not number 0. The cleanup-edit introduced the error into the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->c#->Advanced and uncheck the first checkbox Enter outlining mode when files open.

This will solve this problem forever

Comment: Finaly someone thinking, thank you so much, I would mark your comment as a real answer.

Comment: Note that this setting makes it so that all regions are automatically expanded when you open a code file -- for me this is better than the keyboard shortcut because I prefer to never see collapsed regions.

Answer (score 5):

I have always wanted Visual Studio to include an option to just collapse / expand the regions. I have the following macros which will do just that.

```vb
Imports EnvDTE
Imports System.Diagnostics
' Macros for improving keyboard support for "#region ... #endregion"
Public Module CollapseExpandRegions
' Expands all regions in the current document
  Sub ExpandAllRegions()

    Dim objSelection As TextSelection ' Our selection object

    DTE.SuppressUI = True ' Disable UI while we do this
    objSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection() ' Hook up to the ActiveDocument's selection
    objSelection.StartOfDocument() ' Shoot to the start of the document

    ' Loop through the document finding all instances of #region. This action has the side benefit
    ' of actually zooming us to the text in question when it is found and ALSO expanding it since it
    ' is an outline.
    Do While objSelection.FindText("#region", vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsMatchInHiddenText)
        ' This next command would be what we would normally do *IF* the find operation didn't do it for us.
        'DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")
    Loop
    objSelection.StartOfDocument() ' Shoot us back to the start of the document
    DTE.SuppressUI = False ' Reenable the UI

    objSelection = Nothing ' Release our object

  End Sub

  ' Collapses all regions in the current document
  Sub CollapseAllRegions()
    Dim objSelection As TextSelection ' Our selection object

    ExpandAllRegions() ' Force the expansion of all regions

    DTE.SuppressUI = True ' Disable UI while we do this
    objSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection() ' Hook up to the ActiveDocument's selection
    objSelection.EndOfDocument() ' Shoot to the end of the document

    ' Find the first occurence of #region from the end of the document to the start of the document. Note:
    ' Note: Once a #region is "collapsed" .FindText only sees it's "textual descriptor" unless
    ' vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsMatchInHiddenText is specified. So when a #region "My Class" is collapsed,
    ' .FindText would subsequently see the text 'My Class' instead of '#region "My Class"' for the subsequent
    ' passes and skip any regions already collapsed.
    Do While (objSelection.FindText("#region", vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsBackwards))
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion") ' Collapse this #region
        'objSelection.EndOfDocument() ' Shoot back to the end of the document for
        ' another pass.
    Loop
    objSelection.StartOfDocument() ' All done, head back to the start of the doc
    DTE.SuppressUI = False ' Reenable the UI

    objSelection = Nothing ' Release our object

  End Sub
End Module
```

EDIT: There is now a shortcut called Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion (Ctrl+M, Ctrl+M) for doing just that.