# Collapse ALL #region in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ide, resharper

First of all, no <kbd>CTRL+M</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL+O</kbd> is not the answer. For me, this is collapsing #Region, ///Comments, and Methods and I hate that.

I'd like to collapse/expand ONLY `#region` sections.  I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Resharper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio - Command to collapse all sections of code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982677/visual-studio-command-to-collapse-all-sections-of-code)

Comment: @AliasVarghese That 'duplicate' provides an answer which OP explicitly says they do not want.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>**, **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>** will collapse the current region. You can select multiple regions manually and collapse them that way.

Since the command "Collapse all open region" doesn't exist, you could always try to create a new one; In that case, check out this post: [How to add commands to Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482620/how-to-add-commands-to-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 7):

You can't collapse just regions, but the shortcut key chord:  <kbd>ctrl+m</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl+l</kbd> will do it for everything.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by installing the [Menees VS Tools](http://www.menees.com/VSTools.htm) extension. It's available through the Visual Studio Gallery as well (in VS2013: Tools > Extensions and Updates... > Online > [Type Menees into the search box])

Answer (score 3):

Highlight everything <kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Then <kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> <kbd>CTR</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>  (2 times!!)

Comment: This will collapse more than regions

Answer (score 3):

[In an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28153235/2998072) Ray Pietrzak posted code for a macro that will do this. I used the [Visual Commander extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/deda8ac1-75e6-4068-89ab-b607cee38f2d) to create a new "command", and I pasted Ray's code for the ExpandAllRegions and CollapseAllRegions methods into the command.  I modified both methods so that they take a "DTE" parameter like so:

```
  Sub ExpandAllRegions(DTE As DTE2)
```

and

```
  Sub CollapseAllRegions(DTE As DTE2)
```

and I edited the Run method of the command like so:

```
  Sub Run(DTE As DTE2, package As Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package) Implements VisualCommanderExt.ICommand.Run
      CollapseAllRegions(DTE)
  End Sub
```

The command can then be added to menu, toolbar, or keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this isn't possible without writing your own Visual Studio extension that leverages the IDE. You can [start here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885119.aspx).